# Understand PHP arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I'm a newbie and I have a very basic question about PHP arrays

Code:

```
 While(!feof($file_handle))
  { 
     $SecondRow = fgets($file_handle); //gets row
     $trimmed = trim($SecondRow); //removes extra bits
     $replace = array("'"); 
     $finalstring = str_replace($replace, "_", $trimmed); //Still a string w/o "'"'s

     $CleanString = preg_split("/[\s]*[,][\s]*/", $finalstring); //creates the array

     //print_r($CleanString);    
     echo "Row " . $CleanString[1]. "<br/>"; //??????
   .....
 }//end while
```

the opened file has the following:

```
0001,sparta 
0005,PURCHASING
```

...
...
...

Question:
When I **echo "Row " . $array[0]**,  I get the first column as expected. But when I **echo "Row " . $array[1]**, I get an the "Undefined offset: 1" error. When the string is read into the array (via preg_split) aren't both 
array[0]->0001 and array[1]->sparta set?

thanks.

Comment: why don't you use `explode(',', $finalstring)` ?

Comment: are you just trying to get each column value into an array?

Comment: instead of echoing why don't you do a print_r() or a var_dump() to let you know exactly what $CleanString contains?  These two functions are very useful for debugging purposes.

Comment: I tried explode(',', $finalstring) and rec'd the same result. My trying to break the string into an array so i can insert into a mysql database. I'm i bit confused as to why [o] is as intended, but [1] is not

Comment: Your example works for me. Show me how do you open the file?

Comment: @mephisto $file_handle = fopen("E:\\SysproImports\\Customers-SWDBLoad.csv", "r"); //Get dump file
 
  if(!feof($file_handle))
 {
  $firstRow = fgets($file_handle); // Remove Header (1st) row
  $countRows = 0;
  
  While(!feof($file_handle)) .....

Comment: You sure you did not modify the code you copied to your question?
I just copied it and added a fopen() call. It works for me.
What version of PHP are u using? What platform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your entire code, you're essentially replicating a native function like [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) or one of it's equivalents.

Just pick one and be done :)

As far as determining how to use the array, as noted in the comments use `print_r` or `var_dump()` to guide you. Also read up on [PHP Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: Hi,explode(',', $finalstring)

Comment: ah.. i'll take a look at this function. any ideas as to why [1] is giving an error?

Comment: Thanks for the fgetcsv. Much simpler to use

Comment: Indeed. If it's what you went with, mark this as the answer by clicking the checkmark. Welcome to StackOverflow.

Answer (score -1):

This is because `fgets()` get *one row* at time (one row per "loop").

Comment: What does that have anything to do with how many/few pieces each line splits into?

Comment: He says "`echo "Row " . $array[0]`" so I posted why he don't get array[1]. I see now that he really asked about columns, not rows.

Comment: correct. Sorry for the confusion. I understand fgets, just a bit confused b.c [1] is giving an error